# Getting email addresses for logged in Stripe Customers

Tags: php, e-commerce, stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe Checkout. The action attribute for the Stripe form is charge.php.

On charge.php we have this code:

```
  $email = $_POST['stripeEmail'];
```

Which theoretically grabs the customer's email address, and I can then email the customer a receipt for the order.

However, if that customer is logged into Stripe, stripeEmail does not get sent to charge.php! A customer can be logged in even if I have Remember Me turned off.

This could be fixed by me adding an email field to the form outside of the checkout script, but asking for a customer's email twice is very ungraceful from a UI perspective.

Any idea on how to fix this?

NB: I'm aware that Stripe has a receipt function built in. However, I can't find in the documentation any way to pass to stripe a message to include in the receipt detailing what the customer has purchased and when they should expect delivery.

Comment: Whether someone is using Remember Me or not, Checkout will always post the email address to your server in `stripeEmail` assuming you use Simple Checkout. I've tested this and can confirm it does work as expected. If it doesn't for you, you should contact Stripe support: https://support.stripe.com/email

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce what you're seeing-- see my example here:  https://jsbin.com/mawowupuxu/edit?html,output

Comment: Thanks will try again, I could have made some other mistake and attributed it to this...

Comment: Very strange, it's working now. Was going crazy yesterday...